# Append extra text to "--help" in argparse

Tags: python, argparse

When you run

foo.py -h

OR

foo.py --help,

you will get a "help" message about how to use foo.py and what arguments that it takes. Is there a way I can append to this message? Printing __doc__ for example?

Comment: What is `foo.py`? Something you've written?

Comment: well, foo.py is just an example.

Comment: What if `foo.py` is empty? Then `foo.py -h` prints nothing. You have to tell us something about what `foo.py` contains in order to get a meaningful answer.

Comment: I have some documentations (\__doc__) I need to append or start my help message with.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure, `argparse` gives you **a lot** of customization possibilities.  To "append" to the help (print more after the help message is done), for example, use the `epilog` named argument.

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(epilog="That's all she wrote", ...)
```

where `...` stands for "whatever other named arguments you want to pass to the parser constructor", the message in question will be printed on `--help` after the help about arguments.

See https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html for a few thousand words about `argparse` (written as a reference but with lots of examples) and https://docs.python.org/3/howto/argparse.html#id1 for a few thousand more (written as a tutorial).  Maybe half those docs are about how to fine-tune messages for `--help` or error cases!-)

Comment: Great! Thank you for your help
I used 
**parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description=__doc__, formatter_class=argparse.RawTextHelpFormatter)** 
to make it not to skip on "\n"

Answer (score 3):

The help-formatting function, `argparse.ArgumentParser.format_help()`, looks like this:

```
def format_help(self):
        formatter = self._get_formatter() #by default, an instance of argparse.HelpFormatter

        # usage
        formatter.add_usage(self.usage, self._actions,
                            self._mutually_exclusive_groups)

        # description
        formatter.add_text(self.description)

        # positionals, optionals and user-defined groups
        for action_group in self._action_groups:
            formatter.start_section(action_group.title)
            formatter.add_text(action_group.description)
            formatter.add_arguments(action_group._group_actions)
            formatter.end_section()

        # epilog
        formatter.add_text(self.epilog)

        # determine help from format above
        return formatter.format_help()
```

So, you can either

- customize the strings used (they can be passed as constructor arguments, you're probably interested in `epilog`), or
- replace the default `HelpFormatter` (the `formatter_class` constructor argument) to customize how these strings are transformed into help text

  - the `argparse` module [bundles 3 alternative classes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html?highlight=formatter_class#formatter-class).